# ArrayList search always returns last object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a program to store contact information and has a search function. However no matter what I search it always returns the last object added to the ArrayList. I think this has to do with the for loop but I'm not sure. I am very new to writing code and any input is appreciated.

Here is my search method:

```
    public void searchContacts()
{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Search Menu;\n1. First Name\n2. Last Name\n3. Street Address\n4. City, State\n5. Zip Code\n");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Field to Search: ");
    search = stdIn.nextInt();
    Scanner stdIn1 = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter value to search for: ");
    value = stdIn1.nextLine();

    switch (search)
    {
        case 1:
            for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
            {   
                if(value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName()));
                {
                indexFound = i;
                }                   
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
            {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getLastName()));
                {
                indexFound = i;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
            {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getStreetAddress()));
                {
                indexFound = i;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
            {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getCityState()));
                {
                indexFound = i;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
            {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getZipCode()));
                {
                indexFound = i;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            indexFound = -1;
    }       
}
```

And if it's needed here is my display method:

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.println();
    if (indexFound > -1)
    {
    System.out.println("First Name: " + addressBook.get(indexFound).getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + addressBook.get(indexFound).getLastName());
    System.out.println("Street Address: " + addressBook.get(indexFound).getStreetAddress());
    System.out.println("City, State: " + addressBook.get(indexFound).getCityState());
    System.out.println("Zip Code: " + addressBook.get(indexFound).getZipCode());
    }        
    else
    System.out.println("No Entry Found");

}
```

Contact class

```
public class Contact 
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String streetAddress;
private String cityState;
private String zipCode;

public Contact (String first, String last, String street, String cS, String zip)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    streetAddress = street;
    cityState = cS;
    zipCode = zip;
}

public String getFirstName() 
{
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() 
{
    return lastName;
}

public String getStreetAddress() 
{
    return streetAddress;
}

public String getCityState() 
{
    return cityState;
}

public String getZipCode() 
{
    return zipCode;
}



}
```

Comment: You only need one `for` loop if you place it outside of the `switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each of your `if` statements is directly followed by a semicolon:

```
if (value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName())); // HERE is the problem - the semicolon
```

... which is interpreted literally as "if found, do nothing". After the `if` statement is evaluated, it just always jumps into this block of code:

```
{
    indexFound = i;
}
```

So, if you remove all those semicolons that follow the `if` statement and `return` from the method just after you set the `indexFound`, you should be fine.

The code would the look similar to this - unfortunately I have no way to test this right now...

```
switch (search)
{
    case 1:
        for (int i=0; i<addressBook.size(); i++)
        {   
            if(value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName()))
            {
                indexFound = i;
                return;
            }                   
        }
        break;
    case 2:
    // etc.
```

Comment: oh... now that's embarrassing.. :D I guess that's why indentation counts.

Comment: @Sva.Mu that was exactly it. Kinda is embarrassing but I'm glad that it was something stupid (and simple) I was starting to think that I was completely misunderstanding the concept of ArrayLists.

Answer (score 3):

You should break once you found the 1st element.

```
if(value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName()));
            {
              indexFound = i;
              break;
            }
```

Comment: If I do that it tells me "No Entry Found" implying that nothing is being assigned to indexFound

Comment: @C.fish are you sure you do not have issues with capitalization? use **equalsIngoreCase** instead of **equals** when comparing the strings.

Comment: if I do a break like you said and a break after the for loop it gives me the first entry. Even if I use **equalsIgnoreCase** instead of **equals**

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? Maybe you should define better what the expected behaviour would be.

Comment: I want it to search all the contacts entered into the array and return the one that i search for. right now, no matter how many contacts i put in and what I search for it just returns the first contact entered.

Comment: Please put that in the question. Also, I think the issue is somewhere else in your code, maybe in the addressBook, or the way your Contact class behaves.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a little tunnel vision on this. But thanks for the advice, I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: can you take a look at my Contact class (added to initial post). I feel like that is where the issue is.

Comment: the Contact class looks fine. Maybe it's just the data you are putting in?

Comment: you can also just try debugging and seeing first hand what happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

You loop doesn't break on success matching. It loops till last index.

Make changes as per following code snippet:

```
        for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
        {
            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getZipCode()));
            {
            indexFound = i;
            break;
            }
        }
        break;
```

As per your requirement, it should be re-written as following:

```
indexFound=-1;
for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size() && indexFound==-1 ;i++){
    switch (search)
    {
        case 1:
               if(value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName()));
                 indexFound = i;
               break;
        case 2:
               if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getLastName()));
                indexFound = i;
               break;
        case 3:
              if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getStreetAddress()));
                indexFound = i;
              break;
        case 4:
             if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getCityState()));
                indexFound = i;
              break;
        case 5:
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(addressBook.get(i).getZipCode()));
                indexFound = i;
              break;
        default:
            indexFound = -1;
    }  
}
```

Comment: When I do this it still just gives me the first entry. Would this mean I have a problem with my ArrayList?

Comment: @C.fish : It gives first matching. It breaks inside `if` condition. Check it enter inside `if` as per your expectation. Initialize `indexFound` before switch statement as `indexFound =-1`

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `break` statement in each of the `if` conditions of every case. For the particular code, it should be like this...

```
case 1:
        for(int i=0; i<addressBook.size();i++)
        {   
            if(value.equals(addressBook.get(i).getFirstName()));
            {
            indexFound = i;
            break;
            }                   
        }
        break;
```

Implement this in every case.